# how to prompt optin pop up in youtube video after certain time

Tags: javascript, php

I want to show  a pop up in the youtube video after given time which can pause the video, video can be resumed after clicking on ok on the pop up. There should be a text field in the pop ip to enter email address.

```
<input type="text" id="txt" />
<iframe width="420" id="myFrame" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/vvj4NoMNFpU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="player"></div>

<script>
    document.getElementById("txt").onkeyup = function() {
        var url = document.getElementById("txt").value;

        if (url !== "") {
            var video_id = url.split('v=')[1];
            var ampersandPosition = video_id.indexOf('&');

            if (ampersandPosition != -1) {
                video_id = video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
            }

            // document.getElementById("myFrame").src = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + video_id;
            (function() {
                var stopPlayAt = 10, // Stop play at time in seconds
                    stopPlayTimer; // Reference to settimeout call

                // This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
                var tag = document.createElement("script");
                tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
                firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

                // This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
                // after the API code downloads.
                var player;
                window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
                    player = new YT.Player("player", {
                        "height": "315",
                        "width": "560",
                        "videoId": video_id,
                        "events": {
                            "onReady": onPlayerReady,
                            "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
                        }
                    });
                }

                // The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
                // This automatically starts the video playback when the player is loaded.
                function onPlayerReady(event) {
                    event.target.playVideo();
                }

                // The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
                function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                    var time, rate, remainingTime;
                    clearTimeout(stopPlayTimer);
                    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
                        time = player.getCurrentTime();

                        // Add .4 of a second to the time in case it's close to the current time
                        // (The API kept returning ~9.7 when hitting play after stopping at 10s)
                        if (time + .4 < stopPlayAt) {
                            rate = player.getPlaybackRate();
                            remainingTime = (stopPlayAt - time) / rate;
                            stopPlayTimer = setTimeout(pauseVideo, remainingTime * 1000);

                        }
                    }
                }

                function pauseVideo() {
                    player.pauseVideo();
                }
            })();
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: So what's not working - do you get any errors?

Comment: i am not sure how i can get the pop up inside the video after sometime (like after 10 sec) and that pop up should ask for the email address that i want to save in the database!

Comment: I don't like these kind of adverts // popups so i wont give a full answer but i will hint towards `setTimeout` ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout

Comment: I want the user/viewer to subscribe for the news letter!